# CodeContracts "Required" understanding

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

I tried the following code to enable some kind of not null checking for retrieved entities to ensure they are exist before doing some concrete business:

```
protected T GetRequired<T>(object id)
    where T : EntityObject
{
    var obj = Get<T>(id);
    Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);
    return obj;
}
```

But in compile time I'm getting:
`After contract block, found use of local variable 'obj' defined in contract block`

Am I using `Contract.Requires` in the wrong way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I using `Contract.Requires` in the wrong way?

Yes, you are. `Contract.Requires` is about stating *preconditions* for a method (or property). These are conditions that *must* be true for method invocation to proceed, otherwise you have a contract violation.

Let's take a look at your code:

```
var obj = Get<T>(id);
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(obj != null);
```

Here, you are *trying* to use it to ensure that something is true *after* a method has finished executing (in this case, the `Get` method). That would be a *postcondition* and for that you would use `Contract.Ensures` in the body of `Get`:

```
protected T Get<T>(object id) {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Results<T>() != null);
    // get and return result
}
```

Lastly, this compiler error

> After contract block, found use of local variable `obj` defined in contract block

This message is a result of the fact that you can not use `Contract`s after the contract block, and the contract block appears at the top of body of a method *only*.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are trying to do a couple of things at once here:

`Contract.Requires` should be used on the input parameter directly, e.g. if `id` should never be null, then do like so:

```
Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(id != null);
```

In addition, it seems that you want to guarantee that the result isn't null. Do this like so:

```
Contract.Ensures(obj != null);
```

Similarly, additional contracts can be checked by your helper method (`Get`).